# How many batches can be created in a JOB via Bulk API?

Tags: bulk-api

I went through limitations about Bulk API but could not get explanation on the limit of Batches created per job in Salesforce. I can read Batch limitation but no limitation in Job. Your help is appreciated.

-Thanks
Ankur

Answer (score 4):

Daily limit, not per job:

> You can submit up to 5,000 batches per rolling 24 hour period

Source: http://sforce.co/1avfW6t

A job can be active for 24 hours, so the amount of batches created for a job is at most 5000.